# Is there any way to integrate Google Cloud API's in Visual studio 2019 for C++ console Application using Nuget Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and its client libraries. I am trying to import Google cloud APIS into my C++ console Application using Nuget Package Manager and all the required packages are in 'packages.config' file. But I am not able to run the application and it is throwing below error. Is there any way to run C++ Application using Google cloud APIS in Visual Studio? If it is possible, Please provide the required steps. Find the Screenshot for errors here. [image].